# Intermittent issues burning from NAS drives to BD-rs, What am I missing?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, nas, dvd

---

### Situation

---

I do NOT know what to do... I have 3x 6tb Seagate Iron Wolf NAS HDDs (mounted as a drive letter or logical path) and every time I burn data from these drives to a BD-r 25 GB disk (I have tried different manufacturers and have tried different file configurations {uncompressed, and compressed and chucked into 1gb chunks).

I know my system is a bit old, but it does what I need it to do ATM.

Anyway, I can burn disk (DVD-r, DVD-r DL, BD-r) with no issues. Verifying the compilation, now there is where the problem pops up. What happens is that sometimes, the disks will verify with no problems. However, there will be times and it is happening more often then than before. and the data IS corrupted. With this process, I've coastered about eight to ten disks.

---

### Pertintant H/W and S/W specs

---

- System:

  - MB: ASUS Rampage IV Extreme
  - CPU: Intel I7 3930K
  - RAM: 32GB (Quad Channel)
  - GPU: 2x EVGA GTX 680
  - Optical:

    - 1x LG WH14NS40 (v1.03) or
    - 2x LG WH16NS40 (v1.02)
  - HDD

    - 3x Seagate Barracuda 1TB
    - 3x Seagate Iron Wolf 6TB
  - S/W used:

    - O/S: Windows 10 x64
    - Alcohol 120%
    - Nero 2019

---

### What have I done?

---

- Used Seagate's Seatools:
- S.M.A.R.T. test passes on all drives
- Short Generic Test Passes on all drives
- Long Generic (at the time of this posting, was still going and had 10 hr 51 min left on the NAS drives.
- Used Windows Diagnostics:
- Power shell `Repair-Volume -scan` cmdlet found no errors on all NAS drives.
- Ran Symantec Endpoint Protection on the main system drive and at time of this posting as about 70% complete with only two "PUA" found (not a serious threat)
- Ran Seatools Diagnostics on the Baracuda drives as well:

  - S.M.A.R.T. passes.
  - Short Generic Passes.
  - Long Generic Passes.

**Update #1**
Virus Scan found only four PUAs on my system drive - Not really worried about that, there were cleaned.

---

### My Questions

---

- So, What in the world am I missing?
- What S/W can I use to properly diagnose this and eventually fix it?
- The NAS drives are still under warranty and according to Seagate, are replaceable if there is something wrong, How do I find out if that is the case?

---

### Conclusion

---

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems you think the issues is with your hard drives. I feel that is much more likely the problem is with your burner(s). Nothing you describe hints at the hard drives.

Comment: I've swapped out the burners for a new one and still have the same issue. I'm trying to rule out all possibilities.